# "Start" button missing / no form auto navigation

Tags: docusignapi

The "Start" button has suddenly disappeared from the DocuSigns being sent by our API, and clients must manually navigate through the document to sign.  However, Tests sent using our Developer/Test account come through properly with the Start button and auto-navigation.  Both accounts are set to "Auto Navigation: Navigate Required Fields."  Is there some other setting that controls this, or what is going on?  Thanks.

Comment: is there a "Continue" button instead of "Start" ?

Comment: Are there any signing elements on the document at all?